# AngularJS + Cloud Endpoints: loading endpoints api across multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I have initialized my app following these two guides:

- [AngularJS + Cloud Endpoints -- A Recipe for Building Modern Web Applications](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications)
- [Angular Js and google api client.js (gapi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399419/angular-js-and-google-api-client-js-gapi)

My setup looks something like this:

**app.js**

```
function init() {
    console.log('running global init()');
    window.initgapi();
}

var app = angular.module('app', []);

// Main Controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 'cloudendpoints', function($scope, $window, cloudendpoints) {

    // this is called once eventapi is loaded
    var postInit = function() {
        $scope.backend_ready = true;
        $scope.fetchContent();
    };

    $window.initgapi = function() {
        cloudendpoints.init(postInit);
    };

    $scope.fetchContent = function() {
        gapi.client.cloudendpoints
            .getContent()
            .execute(function(resp) {
                // do something with response
            });
    };

}]);
```

The cloudendpoints service is in its own file, `cloudendpoints.js`:

```
// for loading endpoints service
app.factory('cloudendpoints', [function cloudendpoints() {
    var init = function(postInit) {
        var restUrl = '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';
        gapi.client.load('cloudendpoints', 'v1', postInit, restUrl);
    };
    return { init: init };
}]);
```

Lastly, our scripts are loaded in this order:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="services/cloudendpoints.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

**The Challenge**
This works well so far, because we are only using a single controller (`MainCtrl`). This is what happens in our code:

1. The gapi client loads, then calls `init()`, which calls `window.loadCloudEndpoints()`
2. `cloudendpoints.init(postInit)` loads the *cloudendpoints* endpoint service, which then calls the `postInit()` callback. We can then make calls to the endpoints API from within the `postInit()`.

The challenge arises when we want to create another controller to handle another view of our app. Let's say we create a `ContentPageCtrl`controller — do we then need to once again init our endpoint service? How can we make the endpoint service available to all controllers without having to repeat ourselves?

**My Hacky Solution**
In order to get around this, I `$watch` the `the backend_ready` so that I may only start making gapi calls after the endpoints api has loaded:

```
 app.controller('ContentPageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    /**
     * Make sure that the backend is ready before
     *   running any gapi.client.cloudendpoints calls
     **/
    $scope.$watch('backend_ready', function() {
        if ($scope.backend_ready === true) {
            gapi.client.cloudendpoints
                .loadContent()
                .execute(function(resp) {
                    // put content in DOM
                });
        }
    });
 }]);
```

This means I would need to `$watch` the `backend_ready` variable in every controller in which I need to make endpoint calls. My approach feels pretty dirty, and has problems scaling.

What is the better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach to this would be to leverage the power of `Promises`. you can then have your Service init **once** (inside the service function) and on every method you simply call `promise.then(...)` and keep the logic specific to this method. take this as an example:

```
app.factory('cloudendpoints', ['$q','$timeout','$window',function cloudendpoints($q,$timeout,$window) {

var backend_ready = $q.defer();

checkLoaded();
function checkLoaded(){
 if($window.gapi)
  backend_ready.resolve();
 else
  $timeout(checkLoaded,100); //check again in 100ms
}

var init = function(postInit) {
    var restUrl = '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api';
    return backend_ready.promise.then(function(resp){
     gapi.client.load('cloudendpoints', 'v1', postInit, restUrl);
    }); //we are returning a promise so we can have more
        //flexability inside the controllers (do stuff after the loaded api);
};
return { 
 init: init
};
}]);




//Somewhere inside a controller...
app.controller('someCtrl', ['cloudendpoints', function(cloudendpoints){
 function postInit(){ ... }


  cloudendpoints.init(postInit); //waits for gapi to load, then executes init
});
```