# angularjs add html after server response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following ui-router configuration in my angular app:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state("state1", {
      controller: "controller",
      templateUrl: "mytemplate.html"
    })

app.controller("controller"....
```

In the controller I call a google cloud endpoint API:

```
gapi.client.myapi.method().then(function (resp){

}, function (error) {

});
```

How can I add html using the data from the API response? 
Is using a directive the best approach?

**UPDATE**:

I forgot to mention that the response is from an insert method, this means that this will be executed several times, and each time I need to add the response to the existing elements, like in a timeline way.

Comment: Is data going to be array and do u want to create  a HTML template for it?

Comment: Best way to do what specifically? Question is not clear. Please review [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Js and google api client.js (gapi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399419/angular-js-and-google-api-client-js-gapi)

Comment: How about using route resolve?

Comment: @Shankar Shastri yes I do want to create an HTML template, that's what I was thinking of use a directive.

Comment: So What You Can Do Is Create A Div Like:
<div>{{CodeTemplate}}</div>
Create CodeTemplate In Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngBindHtml incase your response is HTML or bind the response to your template using {{variableName}} inside your mytemplate.html

Directives are preferred if that piece of code is to be used in multiple screens and is also a good practice for big projects.

Thanks,
Abhishek Jain.